# Can someone help me with a crystal report formula issue?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am trying to use this formula and it works except it won't work return anything when my payment is 0.  I have tried 0.00.  I looked up the data filed in sql and it shows numeric (8,2), not null.  Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

if {VMMTICKEH.CMMUPMOD}="AR" and{VMMTICKEH.PAYMENT}={VMMTICKEH.NSALESAMT}then {VMMTICKEH.NSALESAMT} else
if {VMMTICKEH.CMMUPMOD}="AR" and{VMMTICKEH.PAYMENT}>{VMMTICKEH.NSALESAMT}then
if {VMMTICKEH.CMMUPMOD}="AR" and{VMMTICKEH.PAYMENT}>{VMMTICKEH.NSALESAMT}then{VMMTICKEH.NSALESAMT}+{VMMTICKEH.PAYMENT} else
**if {VMMTICKEH.CMMUPMOD}="AR" and {VMMTICKEH.PAYMENT}= 0 then {VMMTICKEH.NSALESAMT} else**
if {VMMTICKEH.CMMUPMOD}="CL" then {VMMTICKEH.NSALESAMT} else
0

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the situation to make it easier to troubleshoot:

- Identify 1 record where the result of the formula is not what you
  expect.
- make the simplest formula that should return the value you expect
  for that record

at that point, the problem & solution would probably become clear
to you. If you still don't see the solution, post an update here providing

- the new simple formula
- the input value(s) to the formula for that record (if you don't know what they are, place those components on the report canvas so you can see them)
- the expected output from the formula, and
- the actual output from the formula.